# trying to add fur on curve following a tutorial

Tags: particles, bezier-curves, hair

hey guys so I am trying to add fur on curve which is literally the first 2 minutes of this tutorial , but I cant find the fur in curve option I just wanna learn exactly what the video says , this is the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCQN5vNgHiI&ab_channel=BlenderStudio

Edit : Turned out that I have been using blender 3.4 the whole time which I had it Shortcut on my taskbar

Comment: What Blender version are you using? The option is certainly there by default in Blender 3.5.1 below Empty Hair on the Add menu. You don't even need the Curve Extra Objects addon enabled. The hair system was added in version 3.5 so if you're using anything below that you're out of luck.

Comment: yup I should have checked before I was using 3.4 which is weird because I downloaded 3.5 before but turned out I had Shortcut for 3.4 , sorry for that I dont know if i should delete the thread

Comment: It might be a good idea to add it as an answer (which you can do yourself) in case someone else has the same problem in future.

Comment: @JohnEason Well, yes maybe - but then we should generalize the question and answer to something like: whenever something does not work or exist like in a tutorial, make sure you are using the same Blender version  :D